# What is the difference? Specifying a file in context-param vs using import?

Tags: xml, spring, import, applicationcontext

Spring and Hibernate stack.

I see that we can specify multiple files in `web.xml` file under `<context-param>` tag.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/appcontext.xml, hibernateconfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

We can also load the config files from `appcontext.xml` file as well:

```
appcontext.xml:

<import resource="hibernateconfig.xml"/>
```

What is the difference or these two are completely different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for flexibility.

What would you do if you needed to utilize multiple spring configuration files, none of which you controlled?

1. In your web.xml, you can specify both files, as in your first example, since you wouldn't be able to add the `import` element to either one of them.
2. You could create a new file that `import`'ed both of them.

Either one will work, as flexibility is something that Spring has strived for.

For reference, here is some documentation for each part:
[import element](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import), [contextConfigLocation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create)

While they are both used for exactly the same thing, it seems that the contextConfigLocation supports Ant-Style pattern matching, where the import element may not.

Comment: So no other difference whatsoever?

Comment: I have added a bit more information.  There are differences in what their capabilities are, but in function, they are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from flexibility one major difference which I have noticed in our earlier project is that, if your context files are dependent on each other, then it can cause problems. Let's say in your appcontext.xml file you are importing bean definitions for some DAO classes, and this is in turn dependent on hibernateconfig.xml.  If you give the entry like this

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/appcontext.xml, hibernateconfig.xml</param-value>
```

in the web.xml then the DAO beans will be loaded with out the sessionFactory (from hibernateconfig) injected into it. This can sometimes cause HibernateExceptions. In this case what you can do is import the hibernateconfig.xml in the appContext.xml before the dao context import, like this:

```
appcontext.xml:

<import resource="hibernateconfig.xml"/>
<import resource="dao-config.xml"/>
```

This will ensure that hibernate configuration is loaded before dao configuration.